# How to get the element value in two sections in xml but ignore if any one of the section has empty element value in groovy

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

We need to get the number element values from the services (there are two service sections). if it(number element) has the value in any of the service then it should take those values and if none of the services don't have number value then it should throw the exception. Please help me.

```
<service>
        <serviceAlias>xxxx/4321</serviceAlias>
            <Elements>
                <Element>
                    <name>host</name>
                    <Interfaces>
                        <Interface>
                            <number>123</number>
                        </Interface>
                        <Interface>
                            <number>123</number>
                        </Interface>
                        <Interface>
                            <number>123</number>
                        </Interface>
                    </Interfaces>
                </Element>
            </Elements>
</service>
<service>
        <serviceAlias>xxxx/1234/</serviceAlias>
            <Elements>
                <Element>
                    <name>host</name>
                    <Interfaces>
                        <Interface>
                            <number />
                        </Interface>
                        <Interface>
                            <number />
                        </Interface>
                        <Interface>
                            <number />
                        </Interface>
                    </Interfaces>
                </Element>
            </Elements>
</service>
```

Comment: I have tried this but I am able to get all number values and getting the numbers values as empty values from second service  and not able to throw exception  . Below is the code I've tried

Comment: for (DataMap service : iteration.getList('service')) {
            for (DataMap Element : service.getList('Elements.Element')) {
                for(DataMap Interface : Element.getList('Interfaces.Interface'))
                        def number = Interface.number
                                if(number) {
                                    data.setProperty("application[name=${Element.name}].number", number)
                                }else{
                                    throw new FatalDGException("Number has no value")